# Insert in a table 2 values

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I need some help again.

I have to insert two values in a table into "**hospital_database**". This table has five columns, and it's called "**personas**". The columns' names are "**cod_hospital(PK)**", "**DNI**", "**Apellidos**", "**Funcion**" and "**Salario**"... I have to insert "**99887766**" and "**Martínez Martínez, Alejandro**" into "**DNI**" and "**Apellidos**", but according to the question, I must to insert into a "**hospital**" where only there's 1 person...

I have to use "insert+select" and my last effort was this:

```
insert into personas 
values (99887766, 'Martínez Martínez, Alejandro');
select dni, apellidos 
from personas 
where count(dni)=1;
```

I tried something like that, and a lot of ways... but It doesn't work like the question asks. I have to use insert+select, so I shouldn't write ";" before "select".

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide additional sample data and expected results.  Are you inserting into the same table you want to select from or do you also have a hospital table?  And where do funcion and salario data come from?

Comment: The questions says: "You have to insert into the table "PERSONAS" a person with "dni"=99887766, with "apellidos"='Martínez Martínez, Alejandro" into the hospital where only there's 1 person." The primary key is "cod_hospital", and every hospital has a code. In the hospital 1 are two people, in the hospital 2 are three people... That's what I am trying to do using "insert"... but I don't know how I use a condition like "where".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I'm still guessing at this a little, but maybe you intend to insert an additional row in the `personas` table if only 1 row exists in that table for a given hospital code.  To do this you need to use `group by` with `having`:

```
insert into personas (cod_hospital, dni, apellidos)
select cod_hospital, 99887766, 'Martínez Martínez, Alejandro'
from personas 
group by cod_hospital
having count(*)=1
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But It didn't save the dates because of there's no any hospital "having count(*)=1"... I mean, every hospital have two people as minimum, so I prefer using another condition better. But thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

insert have several sintaxis and looks like you are mixing all of them

One is insert values  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

the other insert from a select 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

And if you dont include all the field, you have to indicate which fields are you inserting

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
```

Comment: But if I have to try insert a condition like "where" with "insert", how do that? I thought I could use "insert+set" for specific columns, but how I add the condition that I need??

Answer (score 0):

cod_hospital is the table's PK, you could only insert one person per hospital, change your PK to: cod_hospital, dni